keycloak 25.0.6 - unable to start
I'm just beginning to learn the Spring security concepts. I installed keycloak 25.0.6 and tried to run the kc.bat file from bin folder as seen in following snapshot, but getting error as follows:

JAVA_HOME 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17' path doesn't exist.

The JAVA_HOME path doesn't seem to be giving any problems while running the normal Java/Spring programs. Only in the case of keycloak it gives following error.
Please help, as I'm still a beginner to Java coding. Error snapshot - Keycloak error

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak

You should check if your JDK-installation corresponds to the given path of the JAVA_HOME variable:
-> check your file-system under C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17, here you should see a folder structure like:
jdk-17
  |
  |-bin
  |-conf
  |-include
...

However keycloak-25.0.6 requires jdk-21 (Reference: https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-zip).
Therefore i would recommend to download the required version of the JDK and reset the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the new destination-folder (for Windows this should be under System-Properties -> Environment-Variables).
You can find OpenJDK-21 here: https://jdk.java.net/archive/
